# Trouble adding JavaScript inside a custom module

Tags: 7, javascript

I’ve got a question about module development that I need some help with.

I’m building a module which needs to have multiple JS files connected to it. The first file, which has the same name as the module works just fine.
But the rest of the JS files, attached the same way are being ignored.
For example:

```
function mymodule_init() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') .'/js/mymodule.js');
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule2') .'/js/mymodule2.js');
}
```

I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong, if anyone has a suggestion or can point me to some documentation it would be appreciated.

Thanks
Stephanie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's due to the second implementation of `drupal_get_path()`.

You're passing through `mymodule2` as the argument, where it should just be `mymodule`.

e.g.

```
function mymodule_init() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') .'/js/mymodule.js');
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') .'/js/mymodule2.js');
}
```

On another note, if the JavaScript needs to be added on every page (as I'm guessing it does with the implementation of `hook_init`) then you might be better off adding your scripts in using `scripts[]` in the module's `.info` file

> ***scripts (Optional)***
>
> You can now add Javascript in the module's .info
>   file if it should be added on every page. This allows Javascript to be
>   aggregated in an optimal way, and is the preferred method of adding
>   Javascript that most visitors will need on a typical site visit

Source:  [Writing module .info files](http://drupal.org/node/542202)

**References:**

[`drupal_get_path();` API Docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/7)

[Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/756722)

[Writing module .info files](http://drupal.org/node/542202)

Comment: I see! Thanks! I'll be trying this later today and let you know how I fair. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply, thanks again for the help!